# I am getting multiple Root Tag Error on maven OpenGL

Tags: xml, maven, opengl, lwjgl, dependency-management

I have downloaded an automated pom.xml generated file to configure a project folder for OpenGL 3. I used this website :
https://www.lwjgl.org/customize

and over there i selected "maven", "linux", "everything" and downloaded the pom.xml file and after importing it as a project in IntelliJ, I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't a pom.xml file have only one root element?

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pom.xml **snippet** produced and downloadable/copyable from https://www.lwjgl.org/customize does not represent a *complete* Maven pom.xml file.

It is just the child-elements that you need to declare dependencies on the LWJGL artifacts.

Incidentally, there is also a GitHub issue for this (though in a wrong repo): https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/issues/7